# Formatting bound date field in Spring Web Flow

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-webflow

I'm having a problem formatting the contents of a bound Date field in a spring webflow form.  The validation end of things is working, and correctly enforces the date format specified in my annotation.  But whatever I try, I can't control the format of the initial display of the bound Date field (which is pre-populated with the current date).  I'm using Spring 3.1.2.RELEASE, Webflow 2.3.2.RELEASE, and joda-time 2.2.

The date field in the form is initially populated with eg "Thu Apr 04 02:01:06 BST 2013", whereas I want it to contain "04:04:2013".  (Don't mind the funny format with the colons - I'm only avoiding common formats for testing!)

If I overtype it with, eg 13:01:2013 and submit, the binding works fine and the webflow continues.  Overtyping eg 13/01/2013 causes validation to fail with a ValueCoercionException, and the field on the webpage is re-populated with the "Thu Apr..." string.  So validation, at least, seems to be OK.

I understood that the @DateTimeFormat annotations worked as both printer and parser, but I just can't get the printer side of things working.

Here are the relevant bits of my code...

event_add.xml  (webflow)

```
<var name="event" class="project.persistence.DTO.EventDTO"/>
...
<view-state id="event_enterdates" model="flowScope.event">
    <transition on="submit" to="saveEvent" />
</view-state>
```

EventDTO.java

```
public class EventDTO implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private Integer         id;
    private String          name;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd:MM:yyyy")
    private Date            eventDate;
    ...
}
```

event_enterdates.jsp

```
<sf:form method="POST" commandName="event">
<input type="hidden" name="_flowExecutionKey" value="${flowExecutionKey}"/>
...
<div class="grid_3 formitemname"><label for="event_date">Event date:</label></div>
<div class="grid_3">
<sf:input path="eventDate" maxlength="255" id="event_date" class="form9colinput"/>
...
</sf:form>
```

project-servlet.xml

```
<mvc:annotation-driven />

<context:component-scan base-package="project"></context:component-scan>

<flow:flow-executor id="flowExecutor" flow-registry="flowRegistry" />

<flow:flow-registry id="flowRegistry" base-path="/WEB-INF/flows" flow-builder-services="flowBuilderServices">
    <flow:flow-location-pattern value="*.xml" />
</flow:flow-registry>

<flow:flow-builder-services id="flowBuilderServices" conversion-service="defaultConversionService" view-factory-creator="viewFactoryCreator" />

<bean id="viewFactoryCreator" class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.builder.MvcViewFactoryCreator">
    <property name="viewResolvers" ref="tilesViewResolver" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerMapping">
    <property name="flowRegistry" ref="flowRegistry" />
</bean>

<bean class="org.springframework.webflow.mvc.servlet.FlowHandlerAdapter">
    <property name="flowExecutor" ref="flowExecutor" />
</bean>

<bean id="defaultConversionService" class="org.springframework.binding.convert.service.DefaultConversionService">
    <constructor-arg ref="applicationConversionService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="applicationConversionService" class="org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionServiceFactoryBean" />
```

Anyone have any idea how to get my bound date to display in the format specified in the @DateTimeFormat pattern?

Cheers,
Ian

Comment: NB this is only happening in Spring Webflow views.  In views displayed from a regular Spring MVC controller, it all works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a Property Editor.  Spring already has one available for converting Dates.

In your `@Controller` that is handling the request you will instruct spring to convert *to and from* a particular format:

```
@InitBinder
protected void initBinder(final WebDataBinder binder) { 
    binder.registerCustomEditor(Date.class, new CustomDateEditor(new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MM:yyyy") , false));
}
```